# VBA program not running correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I've set up a VBA program in excel that will highlight a cell in a row when the condition of several cells in a given row are equal to each other. (see code below) There are no errors appearing on the debugger, and the designated cell isn't getting highlighted.

In my sample data below, the program would highlight a cell in Case 1's row (since 1=1) and (10=10). Any suggestions on how to get this working?

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer


With Worksheets(1)

For r = 1 To .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    c = .Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Cells(r, 3).Value = Cells(r, 6).Value & Cells(r, 4).Value = Cells(r, 7).Value Then
        Cells(r, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End If
Next r

End With

End Sub
```

Sample Data:

```
Case_1   HT 1   10  STD 1   10  0.008893    0.02564 71  0.35    0.7297
Case_2   HT 1   10  HT  1   15  -0.04434    0.02564 71  -1.73   0.0881
Case_3  HT  1   10  STD 1   15  0.008893    0.02564 71  0.35    0.7297
```

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting? Anyways, replace '&' with 'And' in your `If...Then` statement and see what that does. (Conditional Formatting is _much_ faster than any macro).

Comment: Also, you don't need any of those `.value` properties

Comment: You have lots of syntax issues.`If condition1 And condition2 Then`.. (& is  concatenation).  Also, within your `With` block, you'll want to use `.Cells()` instead of `Cells()` You declare variable `c` and never use it. Lastly, you turn on `Application.ScreenUpdating`, but you're not setting it to `false` at any point in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above comments were good, but I thought I'd put it all together.
You need to change "&" to "And".
Remove; the "Dim c" line, "c = Cells" line, and "Application.ScreenUpdating" line.
I'm running Excel 2010; your code works with the above changes, using either the ".Cells" or "Cells" in the "If" statement.
I also removed ".Value" from each Cell reference, it works with or without it.

```
Dim r As Integer
'Dim c As Integer

    With Worksheets(1)

    For r = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'c = Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        If Cells(r, 3) = Cells(r, 6) And Cells(r, 4) = Cells(r, 7) Then
            Cells(r, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End If
    Next r

    End With
```